# accessing modules relatively from a fixed root with require in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I'm trying to access modules but the nesting gets a bit out of hand

`require("../../../Folder/Deeper/someFile")`

Is there anyway to just use `require("Folder/Deeper/somefile")`

I've tried setting

`require.paths = ['/media/work/Project'];`

but that doesn't seem to work and also feels a bit ugly to me.

Are there any alternatives. Is there any way to write a wrapper for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
require.paths.unshift( '../../..' );
require("Folder/Deeper/somefile");
```

http://nodejs.org/api.html says:

> require.paths An array of search paths
>   for require(). This array can be
>   modified to add custom paths.
>
> Example: add a new path to the
>   beginning of the search list
>
> ```
> require.paths.unshift('/usr/local/node');
> ```

Comment: is require.paths global or file local?

Comment: my error was setting require.paths = [...] instead of using unshift. I cant believe that fixed it.

Comment: Since version 0.8, this doesn't work.

Instead, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369538/can-i-have-ask-require-to-search-for-modules-from-my-application-root or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969175/alternative-to-require-paths-to-edit-require-search-directories-programmatically?rq=1.

Answer (score 0):

Put your application into one folder in the app root (say, `./app`), then soft-link it into `node_modules` like so:

```
ln -s ../app ./node_modules
```

(Note the double dot before `app`.)

This will allow you to `require` modules from your application root:

```
require('app/route/api')
```

For convenience, include this into `package.json` as a postinstall script to run on each `npm install`:

```js
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "ln -sf ../app ./node_modules"
}
```

Windows doesn't have `ln`, so Windows users will need to make a symlink manually. It may or may not work on Windows.