# Alternative to require.paths to edit require search directories programmatically?

Tags: node.js

I'm looking for a way to basically do what manipulating require.paths used to let you do; edit the paths require will search for modules in from within a running program.

The setup (that I can't change, or workaround for various reasons) is that I have a project containing a main JS file within a child directory, which in turn should be able to just `require('module')`, with 'module' being a file inside of *another* directory off in another specific directory within the project folder.

Unfortunately, moving the folder into say node_modules temporarily isn't a desirable solution (if it would even work?). I've tried editing the NODE_PATH environment variable in two ways:

- `NODE_PATH='$NODE_PATH:/home/garmur/moduledir'` which works, but is not desirable as an actual solution.
- `process.env.NODE_PATH += '/home/garmur/moduledir';` from within the program, which doesn't seem to have any effect?

Any help with this is appreciated. I know using node_modules etc. is the desirable solution here, but my hands are tied as to the project layout on this one.

Comment: You can't use `npm link`? https://npmjs.org/doc/link.html

Comment: I didn't actually know about this, so thanks for that; it looks like it'll come in handy for some other things shortly! But unfortunately, for this problem, the only acceptable solution is something that can be done completely from within the program itself.

At the moment it looks like I'll have to create a symlink to the directory within the running program and delete it on process.exit... although this feels a little 'hacky' for my liking.

Comment: Unless you list all the unreasonable constraints the app has to function under, it's going to be very difficult for people to answer your question.

Comment: The one big constraint is that the program has to enable requiring of modules from a directory that would be defined relatively as '../other/' or something like this, but without actually seeming relative (so a `require('someModule')` would equate to `require('../other/someModule')`) without the developer having to do anything but run the program (it must be doable from within the program itself, i.e. prepending a bash environment variable setting before the command itself wouldn't do). Thanks for the help.

Comment: That goes against best practices and makes it easy for someone updating the common modules to accidentally break the app on the next restart. It would make more sense to setup a private npm repository and/or copy the modules you want want in to node_modules when you bundle it for deployment.

Comment: I know, it introduces all sorts of issues with potential conflicts etc. but unfortunately for the meantime these are the constraints I've got to work with. I've settled on symlinking the directory in question to a node_modules folder higher up the projects directory tree than the node_modules folder created by an `npm install`... Thanks for the advice Ryan, it's much appreciated.

Comment: I'm very curious why the constraints exists.

Answer (score 3):

This is hacky because it uses a 'private' method call, but it works. I'm doing this to make the paths sane in my Mocha tests.

```
process.env.NODE_PATH += ':src'; //append custom path to NODE_PATH
require('module').Module._initPaths();
```

Just run that as part of some app startup or bootstrap execution. Then you can just require things relative to src anywhere after that code executes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use relative path for module load, It isn't exactly what are you asking for but could be an option if you need to load modules out of "node_modules" directory:

For instance, with this structure:

```
$APP_DIR/server.js
$APP_DIR/mymodules/handlers.js
$APP_DIR/mymodules/utils.js
$APP_DIR/node_modules/...
```

Inside server.js you can use:

```
var h = require('./mymodules/handlers'),
    u = require('./mymodules/utils');
```

And inside handlers.js you could use:

```
var u = require('./utils')
```